# backbone add a search route to fetch (Rails, coffeescript, backbone)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

In my backbone view I am calling fetch on a collection like this:

```
@collection.fetch
      data: 
        query: query
      success: (collection, response) =>
        #do stuff
```

This works great if I just want to call spots#index in my rails routes. But I want to set up a "search" route in my spots_controller.rb that returns a different set of results. How do I set this up.

Here is my model and collection:

```
class App.Models.Spot extends Backbone.Model

  initialize: -> 

  url: ->
    if @isNew()
      "#{App.getURL()}/spots.json"
    else
      "#{App.getURL()}/spots/#{@id}.json"

  urlRoot: ->
    App.getURL() + "/spots.json"

class App.Collections.SpotsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: App.Models.Spot

  initialize: (models, options) ->

  url: ->
    "#{App.getURL()}/spots.json"
```

Here is the router for a spot:

```
class App.Routers.SpotsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '' : 'index'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Collections.SpotsCollection()
    @collection.fetch()

  index: ->
```

In my rails backend I have a simple controller, here is spots_controller.rb

```
class SpotsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @spots = Spot.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @spots }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just curious how I would add a search method, so when I call fetch, I could tell it to fetch all the spot records based on some search terms. I know I could just add some data params to the call to my spots#index action, then in the index action find those terms, but, it seems like it would be better to tell fetch to fetch the records from spots#search. What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The server is supposed to do the searching? Is there a server-side route for that?

Comment: @muistooshort yeah well, i figure the server would do the searching... is there a way i could do this search from backbone? for example. I have spots that need to be found by geolocation, so wouldn't I have to post the geolocation params to spots#search? or should i post them to spots#index and just sift through the parameters on the backend? i will have many different types of searches so I figure it would be better to separate them into different methods... just not sure how to call different routes on the backend from backbone. thanks.

Comment: Your collection could have a `search` method that would set up a few things and call `fetch`, then `url` can look at the current search parameters to build the appropriate URL for your server, then the `fetch` call will trigger the search and populate the collection with the search results.

Comment: thanks @muistooshort. you wouldn't happen to know of anything online that shows an example of doing this? even if it's not a search, just anything about adding methods to the collection and changing the url... i am also having trouble articulating the terminology to even ask a question like this. seems like there are a lot of ways to approach this. thanks again man.

Comment: @muistooshort another question: how do i check the parameters present in the fetch call from within the url method of the collection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any examples. You don't even have to `fetch` and mess around with `url`, you can do the AJAX yourself and `reset` the collection in the success handler. If you want to use `fetch` and `url` then you could set some instance variables in `search` and then check them in `url`.